# why old Email returns after updating it in firebase and VUE.JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

am trying to allow users to change their primary email in my VUE App which uses firebase as authentication,

the code am using works fine and it gives me that the email has been updated, however after the email is updated I can log with the new email for one time only and once I have logged out then like it has never been changed, and the old email is working again.

What is am doing wrong that keeps getting the old email assigned with the user

currently am using the following code :

```
firebase.auth()
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(oldEmailAddress, currentPass)
.then(
    () => {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.updateEmail(newEmailAddress).then(() => {
            console.log('Email Updated');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Email Error updating user:', error);
        });
    },
    (err) => {
        console.log('log in user error:', err);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this function from firebase/auth as the docs say:

```
const auth = getAuth();
updateEmail(auth.currentUser, "user@example.com").then((result) = { console.log(result) })
```

Comment: This did not solve any issue, are you sure that this is the right syntax ?

Comment: This is the syntax from official docs. And why would you even update email on sign in? Whats the point? Maybe the old one is getting stored somewhere in the state and pushes itself when you log back again? Can I see more of your code?

Comment: As per google documentation, in order to change a user email, that user should have been signed in recently, thats why am using the sign in before updating the email, and its the same issue even if I removed the sign in method.
And there is nothing related to the subject in the rest of the code, its just some normal CRUD operations